# Passing variable to non-dependent jobs in Azure DevOps Yaml Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass a variable from one job to multiple non-dependent jobs. It works for dependent jobs. However it is not working for non-dependent jobs. I have yaml pipeline defined like this.

```
jobs:
    - job: JobA
      steps: 
      - task: Bash@3
        name: var_test       
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |           
            myVar=demo-value    
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myVarNew;isOutput=true]$myVar"              
    - job: JobB          
      dependsOn: JobA          
      variables:
        - name: newVar2
          value: $[ dependencies.JobA.outputs['var_test.myVarNew'] ]
      steps:   
    - task: Bash@3         
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |            
            echo "$(newVar2)"
    - job: JobC          
      dependsOn: JobB
      variables:
        - name: newVar2
          value: $[ dependencies.JobA.outputs['var_test.myVarNew'] ]
      steps:     
      - task: Bash@3         
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo "$(newVar2)"
```

It works fine in JobB. But when I tried it in different downstream job like jobC it doesn't work. Also I can't set the variable in every job as manual validation agentless job is also there in between. I want to use same variable in different non dependent jobs within same stage. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dependencies.X.outputs` relies on X having been declared as a dependency. If it's not there, then Azure Pipelines can't really know to track it as one for that job (with the sole exception that a Job implicitly `dependsOn` the preceding job unless this is explicitly set.

In your case, though, because `JobB` depends on `JobA` and `JobC` depends on `JobB`, the following is equivalent (even if a little redundant):

```yaml
- job: JobC
  dependsOn: 
  - JobA
  - JobB
...
```

It's redundant for dependancy graph purposes, but it satisfies the need for a dependency to be declared so that you can access its output variables.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine. I learnt that variable can be updated in library in run time alternatively.